# Verifying Java platform independence

Tags: java

I have created a jar which runs on Windows. In this jar I have integration with Cognos system and we are doing some file writing and few database operations using Oracle database.

I have got a task to check if the jar will run on Linux system or not.

Is there a way to check if the Jar file is platform independent?

I feel the file writing and db operations should run as they are working now. But still I am not sure of Fie.

Comment: what about running it under Linux either on real hardware either on a virtual machine?

Comment: You can put here whatever you think may not work so that others can guide you. Without knowing what your code is nobody will be able to help you.  Normal file reading/writing will always work on all platforms unless you have hardcoded any OS specific stuff like path seperator, line break etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I have got a task to check if the jar will run Linux system or not. Is there a way to check if the Jar file is platform independent?

The **only** way to be **sure** is to install it on a Linux system, and do a full test of all functionality.  (If that is too onerous, at least test of all functionality that could conceivably be platform dependent.)

---

For the record, there are lots of things that could make your code platform dependent, including:

- hard-wiring the newline terminator into your code,
- hard-wiring pathnames into your code,
- assuming Windows (or Linux) file separators / pathname syntax when assembling pathnames,
- stuff to do with Windows file locking, and other platform-specific file system behaviour,
- hard-wiring external command names into your code,
- using native code libraries,
- making assumptions about the input / output encoding (e.g. assuming that the default is UTF-8, or something else),
- strange things in Swing GUI rendering and (occasionally) behaviour,
- and probably others that I've not thought of.

The only way to be sure that you haven't missed something is to test, test, test

Comment: Thanks Stephen.. That anyways I will be doing.. Just wondering if there is any kind of tool available on the net.(I could not find it though).

Comment: I'm not aware of such a tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check it on linux or mac but you need to check few platform dependent things such as Using correct path separator for file operations, line breaks

You can use [java.io.File.separatorChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) or `System.getProperty("path.separator");` for Path separator and `System.getProperty("line.separator");` for line breaks.